# ajuda em adicionar texto do richtextbox 1 com a richtextbox2 C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox, newline

Olá, gostaria de saber como eu faço, para que quando eu digite na `richtextbox1` o texto apareça na `richtextbox2`, exatamente como se fosse um contador de linha, a cada vez que tecle enter, so que com uma numeraçao propria, tipo a1, a9, b, c4, c5...... 

     **veja na imagem aqui** 

[image: Exemplo pratico]

Answer (score 1):

A numeração que você diz, tem uma sequencia lógica?

Sugiro, colocar um evento no keypress do seu richtextbox1

Transferi o texto do rchtb1 para um array (Split quebrando as linhas a cada Enter)
para cada linha escrevi no rchtb2 e quebrei a linha.

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 13)
    {
        richTextBox2.Clear();
        string texto = richTextBox1.Text;
        string[] linhas = texto.Split('\n');
        foreach (string linha in linhas)
        {
            richTextBox2.AppendText(linha + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Caso queira definir esta sua sequencia, que não entendi muito bem, deve colocar antes da variável `linha` no `richTextBox2.AppendText`.

Comment: Olá, André. Seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em português. A pergunta não está clara o suficiente e, por isso, não é possível dar uma resposta boa o bastante. Quando você tiver reputação suficiente, poderá comentar em publicações para pedir esclarecimentos.

Comment: a sequencia nao é logica, ela apenas é finita, tem um determinado numero de "enters", ou seja, tem um limite de linhas que possa digitar. obrigado pela ajuda @André Alves